# XML DOM - for loop not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, xml, for-loop

This works in Chrome, but does nothing in IE9. It loads data from a XML file on the server.

Here is the code inside the index.html file:

```
        <div id="content"> 

            <script type="text/javascript">

            xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("content.xml"); 
            var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("slot");
            for ( i=0; i<x.length; i++ ) {  

                 document.write("<div id='tables'>");

                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />");
                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />");
                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("location")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  + "<br />");
                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("site")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  + "<br />"); 
                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("tot_power")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  + "<br />");
                 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("proj_power")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  + "<br />");

                 document.write("</div>");

              }

            </script>

        </div>
```

Here is the loadXMLDoc.js:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xmlhttp.send();
return xmlhttp.responseXML;
  }
```

Comment: @Jack  nothing inside the for-loop loads to the screen and no error given..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452581/ies-responsexml-getelementsbytagname-unable-to-handle-non-english-character - maybe this helps

Comment: Well, it works now without having changed anything. I think this is a software issue, I am using Aptana studio, which is free. Still, no idea why..